# Codeigniter redirect errors out to 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

Okay, trying to get a CMS web panel loaded but not sure what is happening. I log in and after the script checks the database for login info, it tries to redirect to the dashboard page. It loads a 404 not found page instead of what it should be loading. This snippet comes from the admin-login.php in the /application/views directory.

```
// Run the query

$query = $this->db->query("select * from adminlogin where binary username ='$username' and binary password = '$password'");
    // Let's check if there are any results
    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        // If there is a user, then create session data
        //$row = $query->result_array();
        if($remember=='on' && $remember!=''){
            $cookie = array(
                'name'   => 'username-admin',
                'value'  => $username,
                'expire' => 86500
            );
            //  $this->ci->db->insert("UserCookies", array("CookieUserEmail"=>$userEmail, "CookieRandom"=>$randomString));
            $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
            $this->input->cookie('username-admin', false);
        }

        $this->session->set_userdata('username-admin',$_POST['email']);
        $user = $this->session->userdata('username-admin');

        foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
            $this->session->set_userdata('role-admin',$row['role']);
        }

        $user1 = $this->session->userdata('role-admin');
        $this->db->select('B.rolename as rolename,A.role_id,A.page_id as pages');
        $this->db->from('role B');// I use aliasing make joins easier
        $this->db->join('role_permission A', ' B.r_id = A.role_id');
        $this->db->where('B.rolename',$user1);

        $query1 = $this->db->get();
        foreach($query1->result_array() as $row1){
            $this->session->set_userdata('permission',$row1['pages']);
        }

        $user2 = $this->session->userdata('permission');
        //return $row;
        //echo $user1;
        if($user2)
        {
            redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }
    }
    // If the previous process did not validate
    // then return false.
}
```

I am brand new to codeigniter so pardon my ignorance in this. What is it redirecting to? I see a couple different admin.php files in different folders as well as a few dashboard.php files also in different folders. I guess I am just at a loss where to begin to look for the problem. I am using apache rewrite enabled and a .htaccess file with rewrite lines. I was also told that this script needs PHP 7.0 which I have as well as php 7.1 and mysql 5.7 for the database.

Comment: is this whole code placed in view directory? If yes Please research about MVC.

Comment: I am not sure, it is basic codeigniter from what I have read. It has routes.php, a controller folder, views folder, application folder, etc. But I will definitely look at MVC and see if maybe an answer lies in that. Thank you